# Add menu items in specific folder?

Tags: macos, cocoa, file-io, dropbox

How to add new folder/file actions into file menu in specific(app determined folder) as Dropbox app does on this screenshot - adds new menu group(Dropbox) and subitems(Get link, Share this folder etc). And how to react on  user action selection from application? Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no public API for doing what Dropbox is doing there. They're injecting code into the Finder process which they're reverse-engineered.